# Flutter testing find.byValueKey() for item in drop down menu doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

My test doesn't found the item in drop down menu with a value key. 
It's works with getText() and the value.

I create a dynamic function to fill every items with a value, a child with `Text(value)` and a key with `Key('sign_$value_item')`;

This is my full form in the app:

```
  static const menuSigns = <String>[
    'aries',
    'taurus',
    'gemini',
    'cancer',
    'leo',
    'virgo',
    'libra',
    'scorpio',
    'sagittarius',
    'capricorn',
    'aquarius',
    'pisces'
  ];

  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuSigns = menuSigns
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            key: new ValueKey('sign_$value_item'), // i even try with new Key('sign_$value')
            value: value,
            child: new Text(value),
          ))
      .toList();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_hPad, 16.0, _hPad, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 16.0),
                width: CustomTheme.customFormSize.width(context),
                child: DropdownButton(
                  key: Key('sign_list'),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: _sign,
                  style: CustomTheme.style.dropDownMenu(context),
                  hint: Text('Choose a sign'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle),
                  onChanged: ((newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _sign = newValue;
                    });
                  }),
                  items: _dropDownMenuSigns,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And strange things, the test works with the Key if the length of value is very long, for exemple more 10 characters.

This is my test:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gherkin/flutter_gherkin.dart';
import 'package:gherkin/gherkin.dart';

class AstroSignValidation extends AndWithWorld<FlutterWorld> {
  @override
  Future<void> executeStep() async {
    await FlutterDriverUtils.getText(world.driver, find.text('AstroDay'));
    await FlutterDriverUtils.tap(world.driver, find.byValueKey('sign_list')); // open drop down menu is ok
    await FlutterDriverUtils.tap(world.driver, find.byValueKey('sign_cancer_item')); // here test not passed
  }

  RegExp get pattern => RegExp(r"I expect the user enters sign");
}
```

Edit: This is my feature file :

```
Feature: Get Astro day
  User should be able to get successfully his astro after cliking astro button.

  Scenario: User get astro in successfully
    Given I expect the "user" 1 sign
    And I expect the user enters day
    When user hits Show your astro button
    Then user should land on result screen
```

Comment: Can you share the scenario outline file where it says `I expect the user enters sign`.

Comment: @Darshan : I updated my message with the file you were asking me for. Hopefully this will help. Thank you.

Comment: I used `find.ancestor` a lot when testing nested types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreated your case. Instead of using `key` property on `DropdownMenuItem`, you need to use it inside it's child, ie, in `Text` widget. That way, since the flutter driver will look for text to be selected when dropdown menu is open, the `key` property will come into play when menu items are displayed and then easier to click on whatever option we pass in the test. It worked well. Updated working code below:

```
final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuSigns = menuSigns
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  //  key: new ValueKey('sign_$value'),
    value: value,
    child: new Text(value, key: Key('sign_$value'),),  // use key here on text
  ))
      .toList();
```

driver test:

```
class AstroSignValidation extends GivenWithWorld<FlutterWorld> {
  @override
  Future<void> executeStep() async {
    await FlutterDriverUtils.getText(world.driver, find.text('Choose a sign'));
    await FlutterDriverUtils.tap(world.driver, find.byValueKey('sign_list')); // open drop down menu is ok
    await FlutterDriverUtils.tap(world.driver, find.byValueKey('sign_virgo')); // selects sign properly
    print('selected sign');
  }

  RegExp get pattern => RegExp(r"I expect the user enters sign");
}
```

And test passes :

[image]

Note: I directly used `Given` statement in feature file and accordingly extended `GivenWithWorld` class in my test. You'll need to use it per your needs.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I created custom step definition at
https://gist.github.com/PROGrand/03b7fa0b49642e691148dc010816cc83#file-click_dropdown-dart

Usage in feature file:

```
...
And I tap the "someMenuItemKey" within the "someDropdownKey" dropdown
...
```